# POS tagging - NLTK thinks noun is verb

Tags: python, nltk

In the following code, why does nltk think 'select' is an adjective and not a verb?

```
>>> import nltk
>>> t = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("select icon from icon")
>>> nltk.tag.pos_tag(t)
[('select', 'JJ'), ('icon', 'NN'), ('from', 'IN'), ('icon', 'NN')]
```

Comment: Well, it IS ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no easy answer, because the Tagger is trained with a statistical model (I found it being trained with a Back-off Trigram Markov Model on the Penn Treebank [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/tnt.html)).

I could imagine "select icon from icon" being a very rare occurrence in the training corpus (if it occurred at all), so looking at the first word, having no more contextual information except maybe for the beginning of a new sentence, it assigned `JJ` as the most likely tag.

If this is a huge problem for you, you can consider training your own tagger on a corpus where more of these kinds of sentences occur or enrich an old one using something like [this](http://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/train_tagger.html).